# Regex Expression to get first word after slash in URL

Tags: regex

Trying to create a regex pattern which only returns the first word after slash in urls. So for example, for

```
https://stacoverflow.com/questions/ask 
https://qwerty.com/search/go
```

return only `questions` for first example, return only `search` for second example

Comment: Why not use a URL parser?

Comment: Why shouldn't it return `stacoverflow`, `qwerty`, `ask`, and `go`? Those are also the first word after a slash.

Comment: In general, if you can't describe what you want  and don't want clearly, it's hard to program it.

Answer (score 1):

To match the first word after the first **single** slash, use the first match of:

```
(?<=[^/]/)\w+
```

If your urls always have two single slashes within them, this will only match the first:

```
(?<=[^/]/)\w+(?=/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a regular expression you should consider using the builtin URL parser and then take the first path part from the resulting path:

```go
func getFirstPathPart1(s string) (string, error) {
  u, err := url.Parse(s)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  if len(pathParts) > 1 {
    return pathParts[1]
  }
  return pathParts[0]
}
```

If you *must* use a regular expression for some reason that you haven't conveyed here, then you could use the following expression, at your own risk:

```go
var firstPathPartRegex = regexp.MustCompile(`^\w+://[^/]+/([^\/]+)`)

func getFirstPathPart2(s string) string {
  m := firstPathPartRegex.FindStringSubmatch(s)
  if len(m) > 0 {
    return m[1]
  }
  return ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reiterating from [**@maerics**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76980730/4541045), don't use a regex if you can and instead try a dedicated URL parser like `urllib3`!

Specifically it's tough to force callers to provide complete URLs

- missing complete URL at all `stackoverflow.com`
- schema (like `https`)

As you're looking for the first block of the *path*

```py
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> urlparse("https://stacoverflow.com/questions/ask").path.split("/")[1]
'questions'
>>> urlparse("https://qwerty.com/search/go").path.split("/")[1]
'search'
>>> urlparse("https://stacoverflow.com/questions/ask?ref=foo#something.else")
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='stacoverflow.com', path='/questions/ask', params='', query='ref=foo', fragment='something.else')
```

Otherwise, use a counter to ensure you have enough slashes